Nuget .NET peer dependencies
Nuget has the concept of peer dependancy, like Node and NPM (https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies)?
I have a library with dependancy from Flurl, used for HTTP requests. It produce this situation:
my-library
    flurl

I would like to define the dependancy from Flurl in the hosting project, not in my library, having:
my-project
    my-library
    flurl

Not:
my-project
    my-library
        flurl

Is it possible?
